# How do I get Maven to print out the test names that failed?

Tags: spring, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3, JUnit 4.8.1, and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have my Surefire plugin configured this way

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I notice when my unit tests fail because of IllegalStateExceptions, Maven never prints out the test names that failed at the end of execution.  Instead I'll see

```
mvn clean install
...
Tests in error:
? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

How can I get Mavne to print out more specific info about test failures?  Right now I have to go digging through the surefire-reports directory to figure out what failed.  Most of my JUnit tests look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class CleverTeacherServiceTest extends AbstractImportServiceTest
{
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your Spring test config is failing before your tests run. You should normally see the failed tests listed in the console, like:

> ---
>
> ### T E S T S
>
> Running TestSuite
>   ..
>   Tests run: 234, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.019 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   fooTest(BarTest)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   fooTest(BarTest.java:23)
>
> Results :
>
> Failed tests: 
>    BarTest.fooTest:23 null
>
> Tests run: 234, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

You could run your tests setting the surefire plugin property `useFile` == false to have all the plugin output sent to the console. I wouldn't configure that in the pom file, but run it like so:

`mvn -Dsurefire.useFile=false clean test`

See [Surefire Plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) for config information.

Comment: I tried the "-Dsurefire.useFile=false" flag but the results still print as "? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext".  In case my question wasn't clear, I'm trying to figure out how to replace the "?" in the test results with an actual test name.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no stack trace or other information listing the tests in error. I created a bogus test with a missing context and got a pretty clear error in the console like I posted above.

Comment: There is a stack trace, but with several hundred tests it is cumbersome to scroll up through all the console output and find the specific failure.  I was hoping there was an easy way to print out a summary, as Maven will do sometimes, but evidently not here.